# Real singleton service on tomcat's and Spring

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, distributed-computing

We have following server infrastracture:

```
2 GUI (handle just user GUI request) Tomcat nodes separate jvms 
2 processing (background processing) Tomcat nodes separate jvms
```

All nodes have spring + oracle as backend (all node have the same databse)

We need to implement TCP listener (based on fix protocol that will receive messages). Important part here is that it could be 
runed only on one server node. Because protocol doesn't support multiple connections.

In other words we need to create this tcp listener only on one server node (processing node from above).  **So question here how we can achieve this?** 
I think we need some kind of communication mechanism between nodes. We can simple create some database table and register services creation/destroy lifecycle there. 
And recheck status before bean creation. But it souns like "reinventing the wheel".Maybe you know some existing ways or tools to do this?

Comment: Sounds like you might want to look into setting up a JMS queue? The two processing nodes can listen to this queue and only one of them will process each message. Do you need the processing nodes to send a reponse back to the message originator? Does it need to be synchronous?

Comment: Ok and who will put messages in this queue? It should do one of the processing nodes.  Maybe you misunderstood original messages processing (tcp listener from above) isn't jms

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood. Are you saying you've already got a TCP listener that is receiving messages from the network? If you get that to send each message to a JMS queue and get the processing nodes to pick them up, would that help? (sorry if I am still misunderstanding!)

Comment: no we need to create this listener but tricky point that it should be created only on single server node, thanks

Comment: Well, just do that: create the listener on one node, and don't do it in another node. You don't need the nodes to communicate to do that. What's the concrete problem?

Comment: @JBNizet do you mean hard-code somewhere that listener should be raised only on node A? It is a bit rough I think. Because nobody will receive messages if node A will not start, or node A will fail.

Comment: Ah, so your question is actually: "what tool or library could I use to start a process on a single node but have one other node failove over if the node doesn't start or crashes?". That's quite a different question. And unfortunately, it's off-topic here.